# Vim :tag can jump to the tag but using short key ctrl+] gives cstag: tag not found

Tags: ctags, tags, cscope

I have generated tags using `ctags -R .`

In Vim I'm able to find the tag when I type `:tag TagName` and it does jump to it.

However, if I have a cursor over the `TagName` and do `Ctrl+]` vim shows `cstag: tag not found`.

I know indeed the `TagName` is in the tags file but why I'm not able to jump with the short-cut key? There are some tags I'm able to jump with `Ctrl+]` not sure why. Also I have `set tags=~/Mycode/tags`.

Comment: It sounds like you have cscope enabled.   Try `set nocscopetag`

Comment: Thanks Mass! yes this does fix the issue :) does this mean i can't have ctags with cscope enabled at the same time?

Comment: @JZ67 well, if you have `cscopetag`, it overrides the `:tag` commands. You can have both, but you'd have to use the individual commands (`:help :cscope` and `:help :tag`)

Comment: Thanks @D.BenKnoble that make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `cscopetag` enabled, you get `E257` on tags not being found (credits Mass in the comments).

Fortunately, the help for this error contains useful information: use `:cstag`! It can do searches in both; precedence is controlled by `'cscopetagorder'`.

Of course, the error and description of `cscopetag` make it sound like the tag wasn't found after searching both, so that's a different issue.

Comment: Mass's suggestion "set nocscopetag" worked for me.
Interestingly now after i set my tags dir in vimrc according to:https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/29030/vim-auto-select-tags-upon-launch
Now jump to the tag works perfectly, i can even comment out "nocscopetag"